# How can I read from an IO::Socket::INET filehandle only if there is a complete line?

Tags: perl, sockets, blocking

When reading from a [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IO) filehandle it can not be assumed that there will always be data available on the stream. What techniques are available to either peek at the stream to check if data is available or when doing the read take no data without a valid line termination and immediately pass through the read?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the `Blocking` option to `0` when creating the socket:

```
$sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(Blocking => 0, ...);
```

Comment: Should that work under Windows, too? It doesn't on my Windows installation and I suspect the OS as reason.

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.2301/IO/Select.pm); it's very often what I end up using when handling sockets in a non-blocking way.